# Threading safety in Google App Engine Python 2.5/2.7 instances / how it works?

Tags: multithreading, google-app-engine, thread-safety

This is advanced question but looks simple - see code (one global variable which increment by each http handler call).

```
some_global_var = 0

class DebugCgiHandler(webapp.RequestHandler):
  def get(self):
    some_global_var++
    self.response.out.write(some_global_var)
```

Q1. The question is what will happen in Python 2.5 and Python 2.7 in single thread mode if variable is set to 1 and concurrent call happen with another request so variable will be incremented in second request before `self.response.out.write(some_global_var)`. What will be displayed in 1st request and what in 2nd?

---

Q2. The second question is what will happen in the same situation if Python 2.7 will be run with multithread mode?

---

Q3. How to avoid variables changes during whole request processing to keep same value til the end protected from other threads?

Answer (score 4):

Q1: In single thread mode you won't have a concurrent request call come in so you don't have to worry about the thread safety.

Q2: With multithreaded on, you may get unpredictable behavior as the different threads could potentially increment some_global_var and display them at different times.  For example, if the timing is happens in a particular way, some_global_var might only get incremented once.

Q3: Use threading.Lock()

Now I haven't answered what results you'll get, because with App Engine, this question is broken as it stands.  some_global_var will be "global" in a particular instance, but you have no control over what instances your requests go to.  So even in a single threaded environment, your two requests may hit two separate instances, in which case you'll see 1 for both requests.  Or they may hit the same instance and you'll see 2.  Your threading issues will apply on top of that.

Comment: I think that you explanation is very good - for me there is no matter if it will be 1 or 2 but matter if it could be change in MIDDLE. I looks that better is use single-threading since multithreading will not work if I will always lock whole call - this variable I want to use for human language setting to keep same language till the end of rendering. Thanks for help!

Comment: you shouldn't use a global for this sort of tracking. A thread local variable or the request object (which is much the same thing) would be more appropriate.